# Trouble with LINQ: Reading objects from database, getting exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I am quite new to LINQ, and I have some problems. I've tried googling for a while, but I still have not found any precice answer to my problem, so I'll ask as well.

I have put up a test database on Microsoft SQL Server, with the two tables "Person2" and "Department2". Person2 has a many-to-one relationship with Department2. Many persons belong to only one department.

Person2 has these attributes:

- id (int, Primary Key)
- Name (nchar(50))
- phoneNumber (nchar(10))
- DepartmentID (int, Foreign Key with name: "fk_Department2_DepartmentID")

Department2 has these attributes:

- DepartmentID (int, Primary Key)
- DepartmentDesc (nchar(50))

The C#-code consists of four classes on two project files: Person, Department and Program (which runs the test) on one, and TabellTest on another.
This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace DBTest
{
    [Database]
    public class TableTest : DataContext 
    {
        public Table<Person> persons;
        public Table<Department> departments;

        public TabellTest(String ConnectionString):
            base(ConnectionString){}

    }

}


using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace DBTest
{
    [Table(Name = "Person2")]
    public class Person
    {

        public Person() { }

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        private int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get { return this.id; }
            set { this.id = value; }
        }

        [Column]
        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { this.name = value; }
        }

        [Column]
        private string phoneNumber;
        public string PhoneNumber
        {
            get { return this.phoneNumber;}
            set { this.phoneNumber = value;}
        }

        [Column (Name="DepartmentID")]
        private int? personDepartmentID;
        public int? PersonDepartmentID
        {
            get { return this.personDepartmentID; }
            set { this.personDepartmentID = value; }
        }

        [Association(Name = "FK_Person_PersonDepartment",
        IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_department", ThisKey = "personDepartmentID")]
        private EntityRef<Department> _department;
        public Department Department
        {
            get { return _department.Entity; }
            set { _department.Entity = value; }
        }



    }

    [Table (Name = "Department2")]
    public class Department {

        public Department() { }

        public Department(int departmentID, string departmentDesc)
        {
            this.departmentID = deparmentID;
            this.departmentDesc = departmentDesc;
        }

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        private int departmentID;
        public int DepartmentID
        {
            get {return this.departmentID; }
            set {this.departmentID = value; }
        }

        [Column]
        private string departmentDesc;
        public string DepartmentDesc
        {
            get { return this.departmentDesc; }
            set { this.departmentDesc = value; }
        }

        private EntitySet<Person> _person = new EntitySet<Person>();
        [Association(Name = "FK_Person_PersonDepartment",
        IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "_person", ThisKey = "departmentID", OtherKey="personDepartmentID")]
        public EntitySet<Person> person
        {
            get { return _person; }
            set { _person = value; } 
        }


    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TableTest Test = new TableTest("REMOVED FOR STACKOVERFLOW.COM, JUST ASSUME IT WORKS");

            foreach (Person pers in Test.persons)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pers.Name + " " + pers.Id + " " + pers.PhoneNumber + " " + pers.Department.DepartmentID + " " + pers.Department.DepartmentDesc);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            foreach (Department dep in Test.department)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dep.DepartmentID + " " + dep.DepartmentDesc);
                foreach (Person pers in dep.person)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(pers.Name + " " + pers.Id + " " + pers.PhoneNumber);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The core of the problem is this code segment in the class Person:

```
    [Association(Name = "FK_Person_PersonDepartment", IsForeignKey = true, 
    Storage = "_department", ThisKey = "personDepartmentID")]
    private EntityRef<Department> _department;
    public Department Department
    {
        get { return _department.Entity; }
        set { _department.Entity = value; }
    }
```

Whenever I try to run the program, I get this exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The number of ThisKey columns is different from the number of OtherKey columns for the association property '_department' in the type 'Person'
>   at ....... etc etc etc

A solution I found when googling the problem suggested that I add the OtherKey attribute to the association, in which case, the Association code becomes like this:

```
[Association(Name = "FK_Person_PersonDepartment", IsForeignKey = true, 
Storage = "_department", ThisKey = "personDepartmentID", OtherKey = "departmentID")]
```

(I've also tried with capital D : OtherKey = "DepartmentID")]

When I do this, I get this exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find key member 'departmentID' of key 'departmentID' on type ´EntityRef `1´. The key may be wrong or the field or property on ´EntityRef`1´ has changed names.
>   at ....etc etc etc

The irony is that the Association-segment from Department, which operates with an EntitySet uses both the keys (just switched on ThisKey and OtherKey), and works.
In other words: I have trouble getting an object of Department from the database in the Person class, while it works to get set of objects of Person in the Department-code.

Now, dear readers and programmers, what do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it could just be the order - you are modifying the private member not the public; did you try this?

```
private EntityRef<Department> _department;
[Association(Name = "FK_Person_PersonDepartment", IsForeignKey = true,
   Storage = "_department", ThisKey = "personDepartmentID", OtherKey = "departmentID")]
public Department Department
{
  get { return _department.Entity; }
  set { _department.Entity = value; }
}
```

Comment: (Author bangs his own head on the desk)

Doh!...

It works now. Thank's a lot :)